# To be "perfect at" something

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Is "Perfect at" a viable expression? As in is it grammatically sound/idiomatic to say something like:

> I am perfect at Maths.

In the same way you'd say someone is very good at it?

I have been using this construction for as long as I can remember, so it has reached a point where it just rolls off my tongue. However, I was surprised when I couldn't find any examples of its usage in dictionaries. If it's not what native-speakers would say, then how can you rephrase it so that it retains the same meaning. Many thanks

Comment: Regarding "perfect at": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22perfect%22&oq=%22perfect%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4269j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22is+perfect+at+doing+%22&tbm=bks

Comment: It's grammatically correct but doesn't really have a correct meaning and would not be used by a native speaker.  "Perfect" means without flaws.  Anything that is a skill can never be perfect, although you could talk about a perfect score on some measure of it, which would mean that the measuring tool isn't sufficiently granular or precise to discriminate the flaws.  Native speakers would use phrases like "great at", "exceptional at", etc.  A specific performance of something might be called "perfect" or "flawless", but it wouldn't be used generically to refer to the person's level of skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "**perfect at**" is grammatically correct and viable, however, the more common is "**excellent at**" and there's also "**very good at**" and "**great at**" *(which is mostly used in the pattern '**great at doing something**')*. I wouldn't say that "**perfect at**" is idiomatic.

Consider this definition of "**being good at something**":

> When you want to express that you are well capable of doing something, the usual collocation is “**to be good at something**”, e.g.